# I want to shred XML data to tabular format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, xquery

```
DECLARE @x AS XML;
SET @x = N'
<CustomersOrders>
    <Customer custid="1">
      <companyname>Customer NRZBB</companyname>
      <Order orderid="10692">
        <orderdate>2007-10-03T00:00:00</orderdate>
      </Order>
      <Order orderid="10702">
        <orderdate>2007-10-13T00:00:00</orderdate>
      </Order>
      <Order orderid="10952">
        <orderdate>2008-03-16T00:00:00</orderdate>
      </Order>
    </Customer>
    <Customer custid="2">
      <companyname>Customer MLTDN</companyname>
      <Order orderid="10308">
        <orderdate>2006-09-18T00:00:00</orderdate>
      </Order>
      <Order orderid="10926">
        <orderdate>2008-03-04T00:00:00</orderdate>
      </Order>
    </Customer>
</CustomersOrders>';

SELECT
    T.c.value('./@custid','INT') AS custid,
    T.c.value('./companyname','NVARCHAR(30)') AS companyname,
    T.C.value('../@orderid','INT') AS orderid
FROM  @x.nodes('//Customer') T(c)
```

I am trying to shred xml data to table, but I get an error:

> XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

The result should be similar to the result here:

```
custid  companyname     orderid  orderdate
1       Customer NRZBB  10692    2007-10-03 00:00:00.000
1       Customer NRZBB  10702    2007-10-13 00:00:00.000
1       Customer NRZBB  10952    2008-03-16 00:00:00.000
2       Customer MLTDN  10308    2006-09-18 00:00:00.000
2       Customer MLTDN  10926    2008-03-04 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return only 1 element, like:

```
SELECT
    T.c.value('../@custid[1]','INT') AS custid,
    T.c.value('../companyname[1]','NVARCHAR(30)') AS companyname,
    T.c.value('./@orderid[1]','INT') AS orderid,
    T.c.value('./orderdate[1]','datetime') AS orderdate
FROM  @x.nodes('//Customer/Order') T(c)
```

Comment: thanks it works..
I wonder if I write SELECT T.c.value('../@custid','INT') AS custid FROM  @x.nodes('//Customer/Order') T(c) without [1] it returns in correct format, but if I rewrite this query SELECT T.c.value('../companyname','NVARCHAR(30)') AS companyname FROM  @x.nodes('//Customer/Order') T(c) it returns error again, what is the difference between them?

Comment: If you look at your xml, you can see that **custid** is an attribute of the customer element, while **companyname** is a child element. You can return all attributes, but to return all child elements you need to iterate through them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **two** nested calls to `.nodes()` to handle the 1:n customers and each with 1:n orders:

```
SELECT
    CustId = XC.value('@custid', 'INT') ,
    CompanyName = XC.value('(companyname)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(30)'),
    OrderID = XO.value('@orderid', 'INT'),
    OrderDate = XO.value('(orderdate)[1]', 'DATETIME2(3)')
FROM  
    @x.nodes('/CustomersOrders/Customer') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('Order') AS XT2(XO)
```

Comment: yes it works.. but can you answer what is difference between (companyname)[1] and (companyname)? custid attribute and CompanyName element both quantity is greater than 1. if it works with attribute custid, why it dose not work with element (companyname)?

Comment: @www1986: I believe it's because you can never have multiple attributes of the same name on an element - therefore, no need for the `[1]` - but you can easily have *multiple* nodes with the same name `<companyname>` under a given parent node -> therefore you need to define `(companyname)[1]` to get the first of those (possibly multiple) nodes